# upload multiple images in a form with multiple fields using Laravel as a framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, laravel, upload

I am having troubles doing the upload multiple images thing for adding new product form. Dropezone.js doesn't work for me because I need to do the upload with preview and keep the images at the client side until he/she hits the add new product button. I also need to give the user the ability to remove a selected image or images.

This is part one. Part two is in the edit product form. Where I need to know how to show the user all the images he previously added and give the user the ability to remove and add images as needed. also the final commit should be when the user clicks on edit button not before.

how should I do that?

This question differ from answers referred to in other questions that I need to also know how to get the data back to the edit form and do the remove of images at user's side until the submit is clicked so I actually remove them.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried the solution written in the questions you referred for the create product form page. i didn't find an answer to try for the edit product form page